# React Frontend fails to connect to Flask Backend after Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I have created my frontend with react and backend with flask.
Everything works when I run my project locally.
However, after I created a docker image, the frontend and backend have lost their connection.

**Dockerfile -> front**

```
    FROM node:14.17.5-alpine
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    
    EXPOSE 3000
    
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Dockerfile -> Backend**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "src/api/app.py"]
```

**And Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  front:
    build: ./Front/multilanding-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./Front/multilanding-app:/app
  backend:
    build: ./Backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./Backend:/app
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=sqlite:////app/src/api/data.sqlite
```

I get two docker images, and they work separately, yet when I try to send a request from my frontend to my backend to access my database, I get this error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/undefined/undefined from 3000-dominioncom-butikenergi-14i7l9a8ve2.ws-eu90.gitpod.io to http://localhost:5000/. butik-energia-front-1    | See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Would really appreciate the help, thanks

NOTE: I have already configured CORS in the backend (app.py).

Comment: to check the connection between minions, sh into front container and try to ping or curl.
`curl http://backend`

Comment: also, pass the backend url as an environment variable to front. I'm unable to see it. so I'm not sure you got it right

Answer (score 0):

From this error message:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/undefined/undefined from
> 3000-dominioncom-butikenergi-14i7l9a8ve2.ws-eu90.gitpod.io to
> http://localhost:5000/

it seems that you hosted your docker-compose setup remotely and are now trying to access it via a public URL. Read on if I guessed right.

The problem here is that your frontend executes in your browser (client-side rendering) and not on the remote host. So when the fronted tries to access `localhost:5000`, it's the localhost of your PC/laptop, not the localhost of the remote host on gitpod.io.

To fix this, you need to:

1. Make your backend public, i.e. have a gitpod.io public link to it like the one that you have for the frontend;
2. Let your frontend know that the backend is accessible via the public link from step 1 and not `localhost:5000`.

With this done, next time you open your public frontend URL in the browser, it will try to send requests to the public backend URL and this should work.